# Error while uploading game on Windows Phone store

Tags: windows-phone-8, app-store, windows-phone

I am uploading a game on Windows Phone store. While uploading the game, in "App Info", I need to provide game certification for various organization. After selecting that when I press save I am constantly getting below getting error. I tried to Google it, but no solution. Anyone has idea what I am doing wrong?

**PS : One thing I doubt is I am choosing certificates files only for ESRB & PEGI. For other organizations I don't know how to get certificates due to lack of documentation. When I choose only ESRB & PEGI it worked.**

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're saying that if you specify some certification programs but then don't provide the certificates it fails. I'd guess the issue is that you're not providing the certificates.

Comment: Ok, but where can I get all the certificates? Microsoft docs provide info for only limited organization. For other it's saying contact their website but in those websites there's nothing to get the certificate. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj206734(v=vs.105).aspx) out.

Comment: You are looking for this link :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694080.aspx
Here you get all the relevant informations, and links to the application forms. It is the same for windows phone. But for the direct windows phone site go to this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206734%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Above link is for Windows 8 apps, I am asking about Windows Phone apps.